# issues deploying Rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to deploy a site on a commercial hosting service. (JustHost.com)
I am having the following issue running `bundle`

```
# bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/cache/rake-10.3.0.gem] in /home5/<username>/<sitename>
An error occurred while installing rake (10.3.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.3.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am able to successfully run the `gem install` command:

```
# gem install rake -v '10.3.0'
Successfully installed rake-10.3.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rake-10.3.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for rake-10.3.0...
```

But I get the same error re-running bundle. Furthermore, I don't think I was actually able to install rake - its location is not writable by me and the version is unchanged:

```
# which rake
/usr/bin/rake

# rake --version
rake, version 0.9.2.2
```

I also tried updating my Gemfile to use rake 0.9.2.2. but ran into the same issue:

```
# bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/cache/rake-0.9.2.2.gem] in /home5/<username>/<sitename>
An error occurred while installing rake (0.9.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: are you using rvm? are you sure the right bundle is being run? I think this might be a problem with which ruby is being executed on your system.

Comment: I don't have rvm on the host. My ruby version is 1.9.3p429

Comment: I am also having this issue. Exact same one...using hostmonster for hosting. As such RVM is NOT installed as they don't allow for multiple ruby instances

Comment: has there been any progress on this?

Comment: Dan - I don't know if this helps in your specific environment, but on JustHost I figured out my issue was that I needed to use the control panel to set up my rails app instead of trying to set it up at the command line. In cpanel, there is a link to 'Ruby on Rails' under 'Software/Services' - from there you go to a page where you set up your rails app. It's a bit clunky - eg, you can't edit your app once you've set it up, you can only delete and recreate. Also, it sometimes takes a few minutes for changes to propogate. But I've had no issue running bundle with the app I set up that way.

Comment: Also, I learned that deployment on JustHost uses Phusion Passenger, which I was unfamiliar with, but is pretty straightforward. Upload your files, recompile your assets if necessary: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and then make a trivial update to the 'restart.txt' file: `touch tmp/restart.txt` (this tells Passenger to restart the server on the next page hit). Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

What I did to get around this was update the .bashrc file per the instructions [here](https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/rails).  I also had to setup a javascript runtime so I used gems rubyracer with execjs.